# Swagger JAX-RS with Jersey 1.19 gives 'Conflicting URI templates' error

Tags: java, jersey, swagger

I am trying to add Swagger to an existing application that uses Jersey 1.19. For adding Swagger to the application, I have been following this guide: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-1.X-Project-Setup-1.5.

When I deploy the application on Apache Tomcat, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template / for root resource class io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource and the URI template / transform to the same regular expression (/.*)?
```

The odd thing is that my Jersey servlet is not deployed at the root context, but at the /api/* context as shown in the web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApp Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>app.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApp Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My MyApplication class is defined below:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private final Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
private final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

public MyApplication() {

    MyResource resource= new MyResource();

    singletons.addAll(Arrays.asList(resource));

    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage(getClass().getPackage().getName());
    beanConfig.setTitle("REST API");
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);

    classes.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    classes.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
}

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    return classes;
}

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}}
```

I have tried other configurations, such as defining the Swagger servlet in the web.xml file instead of using the BeanConfig, but the same error still occurs. I have gotten Swagger to work this way on a different project that uses Jersey 2, but unfortunately the current project has to remain on Jersey 1.19. Here is the Swagger dependency defined in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2:** Looks like version 1.5.8 of swagger-core fixes that issue. See [this commit](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/commit/f8c69c89e6fee93076241e031f9ea98c375e725e) for details.

---

**Update:** Instead of adding Swagger resource as sub-resource it much easier to just override `@Path` mapping. See *Solution 2* for details.

---

I was facing exactly the same problem. The cause of that is Swagger resource being mapped to root `@Path("/") public class ApiListingResource`.

---

## Solution 1 - No concurring mappings

One simple and inflexible way around it, is **not** to define any resource mapping to root path `@Path("/")`.

---

## Solution 2 - Override `@Path` mapping

#### 2.1 Override Swagger classes

`ApiListingResource` should get a new `@Path` mapping

```
package my.api.package.swagger

import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("swagger")
public class ApiListingResource extends io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource {}
```

`SwaggerSerializers` should get new package

```
package my.api.package.swagger;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class SwaggerSerializers extends io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers {}
```

#### 2.2 Configure overriden classes

Add `my.api.package.swagger` instead of `io.swagger.jaxrs.listing` in Swagger package config.

---

## Solution 3 - Swagger resource as sub-resource

Other solution is to move Swagger to a different path, allowing your resources to be mapped anywhere you like. To achieve this you need to:

#### 3.1 Remove `ApiListingResource` from provider classes.

if you subclass `Application`:

```
public MyApplication() {
    //init BeanConfig
    //add your resource classes

    //classes.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    classes.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
}
```

if you configure via `web.xml` using `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` param:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>your-rest-api</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            {your_application_packages},
            <!--io.swagger.jaxrs.json,-->
            <!--io.swagger.jaxrs.listing-->
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers,
            io.swagger.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

BTW, I have noticed that GF 3.1.2.2 with Jersey configured using `<filter/>` in `web.xml` does not work with Swagger due to [Grizzly related bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1047).

#### 3.2 Add `ApiListingResources` as a subresource to one of your resources

```
@Path("/") 
class RootResource {
    @Context ServletContext context;

    @Path("/swagger")
    public ApiListingResource swagger() {
        return new ApiListingSubResource(context);
    }
}
```

As `ApiListingResource` is now not managed by Jersey, it does not get `ServletContext` injected. To overcome this problem you have to pass it as a constructor parameter, and for that subclass `ApiListingResource` and provide proper constructor:

```
// context has 'default' visibility
// so we need to stay in the same package 
// to be able to access it
package io.swagger.jaxrs.listing;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

public class ApiListingSubResource extends ApiListingResource {
    public ApiListingSubResource(ServletContext sc) { this.context = sc; }
}
```

Now your Swagger descriptors will be under `http://hostname/app-path/swagger/swagger.json` and you will still be able to use the root resource.

It's a little bit longer way , but works! Hope that helps.

Comment: Upgrading from 1.5.0 to 1.5.8 fixed it for me, thanks!